# collectionView not access because of UITransitionView and UIDimmingView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

[image]

because of UITransitionView and UIDimmingView can't access UICollectionView so how to remove this.

Comment: you have search controller on top of collection view, why is that? remove search controller

Comment: i can't able to remove that because collectionview show the result of user search

Comment: so you need to put collectionview inside searchController or hack it, use search bar without search controller